# NSMutableDictionary removeObjectForKey strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

If i set an object in a `NSMutableDictionary` this way:

```
NSString* idFriend = @"Superman";
[reqWaitDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:idFriend];
```

It doesn't work when i try to remove it like this:

```
[reqWaitDictionary removeObjectForKey:idFriend];
```

In order for it to work, i have to set the `NSMutableDictionary` this way:

```
[reqWaitDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",idFriend]];
```

For me this is strange because the `idFriend` is already a `NSString`. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Do you mean `NSMutableDictionary`? Because `removeObjectForKey:` isn't a method on `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @bruno Strange ! But it works for me.

Comment: I think it's the way i set the object in NSMutableDictionary

Comment: I changed the question a bit

Comment: There's something you're not telling us.

Comment: I'm working on a code with two years...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will works fine if you declare correctly. Declaration type only different.

Try like this:

```
[reqWaitDictionary setObject:idFriend forKey:@"someKey"];
```

Comment: I changed the question a bit

Comment: Try my new solution which am edited related to your new edit.